# Creating an Object(class) structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I am trying to create a Javascript application which displays initially `Countries` information, Selecting a country all the `Regions` will be displayed and
Selecting a Region all the related `Cities` will be displayed and 
at the end by selecting a City `Hotels` list in that city will be displayed.

Fron `Country` to `City` all the informations are lomost same. like

```
id
name
goedata
etc..
```

What will be the best way to design the `HotelLocator` application.

I am interested in using some kind of classes for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to create a dictionary that will contains all regions each region as value will hold dictionary with all cities and hotels . So when region is selected you will retrieve dictionary with all cities . Each city will hold all hotels .

It will be a dictionary which as value holds dictionary . Actually it's designed for json . You don't need to create a class . Every array in JavaScript is a dictionary.

Answer (score -2):

something like:

```
class HotelLocator {

   public countrySelector(){
      return Map<Country, Cities>
   }

   public citySelector(Map<country, city>){
      return Map<City,Hotels>
   }

}
```

Basically one class is more then enough. Just follow a modular approach to take input and return what is required.

Comment: oh sorry i didn't realize that